# Appbundle crashes flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

If you compile the Appbundle application and upload it to the test channel in google play, then when you open the application, it immediately crashes. If you compile apk and install it on your phone, then everything is ok. How can I find the error after compiling the Appbundle? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you included firebase? If yes make sure to add sha1 and sha256 from Google Play in firebase console and add the json file in your project and upload another bundle

Comment: Thanks Bro. It helped me!!